# Is there any function in R to check whether a line of code returns error or not?

Tags: r, debugging

Is there any function in **R** that returns `false` if a line of code produces error?

Comment: What do you mean? Before runtime? What type of errors you regard: syntax, semantic, runtime?

Comment: You can combine `tryCatch` and `inherits` to verify the returning `class` of the object.

Comment: Depending what you're after, either yes or 'halting problem' I think you need to be more specific.

Comment: I am trying to do a simple job in genetic programming. I was looking for functions such as try, tryCatch and inherits. However it seems that it depends on the error type. I need to read about debugging. Thanks for commenting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean something that would be familiar to shell developers, where you can run arbitrary command and **then** inspect whether it succeeded or failed, then the answer is **no**.

In R, all errors are fatal - they immediately terminate execution of program. There is no way to check if something has failed afterwards, because "afterwards" is never reached.

What you can do is wrap some part of application into special block that will temporarily suspend severity of errors and allow to respond to them. This can be done using [`try`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/try.html) or [`tryCatch`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html), where first one is wrapper around second (so they basically do the same thing).

Please note that you can't recover from syntax errors this way - these will be caught by parser before any code is evaluated.

Overall, I would recommend reading "[Debugging, condition handling, and defensive programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html)" chapter in *Advanced R* book. Feel free to ask further questions if you encounter specific problems.